# How to save my boss' face when his evidence to motivate us is wrong?

Tags: team, leadership, teamleader, confidence, self-confidence

One day my boss sent in our team chat group a screenshot of his conversations with one of his former subordinates who is now working in a giant. In a conversation my former colleague(the mentioned guy) kind of flattered him that what she was doing in our company was much more advanced than what she is doing now in the new company. And thus my boss encouraged us that we should be confident in what we are doing now.

But many of my colleagues and I just disagreed with his blind self-confidence, and we discussed the facts and the true gap offline. One of my colleagues said in the chat group that it would be untrue and provided some strong evidence, and our boss didn't say anything more. I think he may have realized his mistake.

I think his motives are good but he didn't find the right method, but I don't know how to save his face and realize his purpose: build the team's confidence and help the team to grow? Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to do anything? Just pretend it never happened.

Comment: I think you are asking two questions. Firstly, how to help your boss recover from this mistake and like Philip says, I don't think you need to. Mistakes are an inevitable part of trying stuff, just forget about it and move on. The second part is about building the team's confidence in what they are doing and to answer that I think you should ask a separate question detailing what you *are* doing and why the team is not confident.

Comment: What is untrue - this chat? That means your boss has faked it?

Comment: @puck The advantage is not true.

Comment: @mattfreake It seems that we lack confidence, but we don't know how to encourage ourselves.

Comment: @Weiterbildung so to be clear about that (sorry but I am not at all), your ex colleague provided false facts that your boss believed, mainly because he has no reason to doubt them?

Comment: @puck The ex-colleague only flattered him but gave him no (false) facts/evidence.

Comment: To be honest I think there is a lot missing to understand this situation as someone who only has your written text but not your thoughts and stuff you know but didn't tell us :-) What is the "advantage" in your comment that isn't true? Your question doesn't mention an advantage. *"facts and the true gap"* - what are they? *"it would be untrue"* - you are a little fuzzy here, what is "it"? *"he may have realized his mistake"* - can you explicitely name this mistake? Believing "it" is true? What did ex colleague tell your boss and what did your boss add mistakenly?

Comment: So... let's call her X, left your company to work elsewhere and told Boss that "the work I was doing under you was much more advanced than my new job". But you and your colleagues have got together and decided X is a liar, and that actually she's doing more advanced work in her new place? What's your evidence for that?

Comment: @Showsni ... I and my colleagues have got together and decided that X said was insufficiency for my boss to reach the conclusion that our technology is much advanced than that in X's new place.

Comment: I don't understand how you can even call any of these things facts. People say things like this all the time. "I miss you guys... I learned so much form working with you... Without working with you, I NEVER could have succeeded in my new job... I wish I was still working with you."  The last one is untrue, because if she wanted to stay she would have, but the rest is meaningless,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just take him at his word and don't get involved with other people putting him down.

Nothing constructive about joining in.

Answer (score 1):

If that is now the last message in the group chat, I would send a message to change the focus of the conversation, some new result, or some work question, just to move on. Otherwise, just ignore it.